# XPath how to get parents sibling inside node

Tags: xpath

This is my HTML:

```
<tr>
         <td bgcolor="ffffff" height="14" width="112"><p class="boldblack">&nbsp;Price:</p></td>
         <td bgcolor="ffffff" width="296"><p class="cena2">9 000 $</p></td>
         <td bgcolor="ffffff"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to take the `9 000`

#### What I have tried

```
.//p[contains(., 'Price:')]
```

which gives me the `Price:` node. Now, how can I reach the `9000` from the `Price` node?

#### Note

I can't use XPath like td[2] because I am having a dynamic content. I just know that I will have the `price` node and their parent's brother will have the `9000 $`

#### Update 1

I can't rely on class either because the structure of the HTML is very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to simply to rely on the class name (`cena` from Russian is `price`):

```
//p[@class="cena2"]/text()
```

If you want to rely on the preceding `Price:` label:

```
//tr[td[1]/p[contains(., "Price:")]]/td[2]/p/text()
```

Another option would be to check whether the text ends with `$` sign:

```
//tr/td/p[ends-with(., "$")]/text()
```

As you see, there are multiple options, it is hard to tell which one is more reliable since you haven't showed the complete HTML code. You can even combine all 3 options I've presented.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't want to relay on class, I want to relay on the node `Price` and then its father's brother inside node

Comment: +1 your second update helps me a lot , will accept it when the system allows , many thanks

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli thanks, Marco, for the another interesting question (out of upvotes for today, will +1 you later).

Comment: sorry I didn't understand u. my english is boor